# Find root in finite field

Tags: algorithms, nt.number-theory

What efficient algorithms exist for the solving $x^N = a$ in GF(q)?
What are their complexities?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields

Comment: Thank you! But it is too general method.
Is there anything more specific?

Comment: Which of $x$, $N$, $a$ are given and which are the variables to be solved for?

Comment: N and a are given. 

Comment: I will assume that $a,N,q$ are given and you want to solve for $x$. Even then, there is no simple single answer. The problem changes if $q$ is a big prime, versus the case $q$ a big power of a small prime, versus intermediate cases. It also changes if $N$ is big versus $N$ small. If are interested in a particular range, making that explicit will help getting a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasting the title of your question into Google gives references like
http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~astolk/monday/notes/stolk-roots.pdf and
http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/Preprints/roots.pdf
-- this should answer your question.